# Invisible characters in Java Strings

Tags: java

```
String a = "Hello\u200e";
String b = "Hello\u200f";

System.out.println("a = '" + a + "' and b = '" + b + "' are length "
                     + a.length() + " and " + b.length()
                     + ", equals() is " + a.equals(b));
```

The code in the above code snippet produces the following output.

> a = 'Hello‎' and b = 'Hello‏' are length 6 and 6, equals() is false

Although the value of both `a` and `b` displayed on the console is `Hello‏`, `a.equals(b)` returns `false`. How?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`U+200E`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) and [`U+200F`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) are **not** printable characters.  They're both control characters which dictate how the text should be rendered - either left to right, or right to left.

You won't see these in the terminal, and they shouldn't be equivalent strings.

<sup>`0x200E ^ 0x200F != 0`</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Because the character sequences are not identical. Just because it appears the same on the console does not mean the objects are identical.