# Java -> 2 lists with the same content don't match

Tags: java, list, comparison

I have 2 java lists

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I load some data from the database to the first one and from diffrent database to the second one.

The strings in the lists look exactly the same:

```
3441134 China Ap F
3441134 China Ap F
```

But when I check:

```
if(list1.get(1).equals(list2.get(1))){
logger.info("true");
}
else{
logger.info("false")
}
```

I always get

> false

Can somebody say why? I checked white spaces and it's the same too.

Comment: Are you sure that the second String in both lists are same.

Comment: Why don't you log `list1.get(1)` and `list2.get(1)`? You are most likely not comparing what you think you are comparing.

Comment: Debugging helps.

Comment: The strings are different, try to put a breakpoint into the if and look the strings values, maybe something related to charset encoding from those different databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is something related with character encoding, you may be seeing the same string in console and debug but internally they have a extra invisible byte because of the encoding.

Try to look at: [Invisible characters in Java Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548875/invisible-characters-in-java-strings?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) you will understand what i am saying.